# Conjugate of a hermitian operator also hermitian

Tags: operator-theory

I want to prove that if $D$ is a hermitian operator, then $D^*$ is also a hermitian operator.

$D$ is a hermitian operator implies that $(f,Dg) = (Df,g)$ where $f$ and $g$ are functions.

Therefore, I want to prove that $(f,D^*g) = (D^*f,g)$.

I know that $(f,D^*g) = (D^*g,f)^* = (\int_a^bDg^*f\mathrm{d}x)^*$. I suppose that $(\int_a^bDg^*f\mathrm{d}x)^* = \int_a^bD^*gf^*\mathrm{d}x$.

Nevertheless, I don't know how I will be able to have $D^*$ act on $f$ instead of acting on $g$, which appear to be necessary in order to complete the proof...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people use Hermitian to mean symmetric, i.e., that
$$
                  (Df,g) = (f,Dg),\;\;\; f,g\in\mathcal{D}(D).
$$
If that's the case, then the result is not true. There are simple examples of densely-defined closed symmetric linear operators $D$ with adjoints $D^{\star}$ which are not symmetric. A simple example is $D=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^{2}[0,\infty)$ with domain $\mathcal{D}(D)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous $f \in L^{2}$ for which $f' \in L^{2}$ and $f(0)=0$. The adjoint of $D$ has the same domain except that no condition is imposed at $0$. $D$ is maximally symmetric, and has no selfadjoint extension.

Answer (score 0):

$(D^*v,w)=\overline{(w,D^*v)}=\overline{(Dw,v)}=\overline{(D^*w,v)}=(v,D^*w).$

Answer (score 0):

"$D$ is Hermitian" means $D = D^*$.  So anything that $D$ is, $D^*$ is too.